# Where do constructors go for classes that extend or implement other classes

Tags: java, class, constructor, comparable

I need to create a class called Student that has three private fields: first name, last name, and GPA. Normally, you place a class constructor between the class name and the left bracket, like so: `public class Student (firstName, lastName, gpa) {...}`

My Student class has to implement the Comparable interface, so my class signature looks like this: `public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {...}` In this situation, where does my constructor go?

Comment: `public class Student (firstName, lastName, gpa) {...}`  What?  No...  `public class Student { public Student(String firstName, String lastName, double gpa) {..} }`...

Comment: It's a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), not a conductor, and it doesn't go in the declaration of the class.

Comment: If you are talking about `extends`, rather than `implements`, well then a discussion on constructors is releveant: google the `super` keyword in java to find more info

Comment: @LouisWasserman I got that from this example in the Oracle Java Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are writing a class, the constructor is a method (or "like a method" depending on your semantics) inside the class. It is not the same as the class declaration.

```
// This is the class declaration, where the "implements" clause goes
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
     ...
     // This is the constructor, which can take whatever parameters you want
     public Student(String firstName, String lastName, float gpa) {
         ...
     }

     // This is the implementation of a method declared by the Comparable<Student> interface
     @Override
     public int compareTo(Student other) {
          ... 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no change to the constructor required.  What *is* required is that you implement the methods prescribed by the interface.

That is to say, you could have the same constructor you're using (provided that you provide types for your parameters, which you are not, but you *must*), but you are required to implement `compareTo(Student other)` somewhere in your class.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor would stay the same, regardless of the `interface`(s) being used on the class.

The `interface` would only stipulate that you implement 0 or more methods but does not change how the class constructor should be written.

Comment: Maybe I phrased my question wrong.  I understand how to use the comparable interface, and I know that what's inside the constructor will not change. Where in the decoration of my class does the constructor go if I implement Comparable? (I.e. after the class name, right before the right bracket, etc.)

Comment: The constructor should typically be at the top (although I am of the impression that it doesn't matter where in the class it goes, so long as it is present). 

To re-iterate, implementing an interface will not change the constructor.